# Jquery val(); not getting value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value from an input into a cell of a table and I do not know why the val(); is not working(not getting the value). I have checked everywhere, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988992/jquery-val-not-working), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-get-textbox-value-with-jquery/) but with little success. I belive my code is correct. Am I missing something about the rendering or my code is wrong? All help will be apreciated.

thank you in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_studies_button"); 
 var studies         = $("#studies").val();
 
    
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append('<tr>' +
        '<td>' + studies + '</td>' +
        '<td>Que tal</td>' +
        '<td>Pitt</td>' +
        '<td>35</td>' +
        '<td>New York</td>' +
        '<td><a class="remove_field">Remove</a></td>' +
  '</tr>'); 
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent().parent().remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 

<div class="form-horizontal pull-right col-xs-6">
 
  <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Studies:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
              <input class="form-control" maxlength="100" type="text" id="studies" required="required"  placeholder="Studies">
            </div>
        </div>
          
  <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right add_studies_button" style="margin-top:7px;">Add</button>
      
              <span></span>
     
     
            
            </div>
          </div>
  
  
   <div class="table-responsive col-xs-6">          
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Studies</th>
        <th>School</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="input_fields_wrap">
 
 
    
 
 
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the statement:

```
var studies = $("#studies").val();
```

inside the `click` listener:

```
$(add_button).click(function(e) {
```

This is so that it gets the value of the `#studies` input box *at the time of click*. The variable `studies` in your code is set at the beginning and never updated (it does not automatically update to the value of `#studies`).

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kvazq6qz/).

Comment: Thank you!! I did not know about that issue. You never go to bed without learning something. Thank you again!